# Texture flickering

Tags: rigging

I've created a Minecraft Horse rig but for some reason when I try to close the eyes with the eyelids bones the texture starts flickering, and the weirdest thing is that it won't flicker if the subdivision modifier is turned off
[image: Example]
(https://gyazo.com/313cda21ea6c8f39aa25ead7f8e2db21.gif)

I have another rig where I did the exact same thing and the texture of it doesn't flickers like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because your mesh is getting quite distorted when you move the rig control past where it should stop. The subsurf modifier can make a mess out of extremely distorted meshes, which is why it only occurs with the modifier enabled.

The solution is to limit the motion of the eyelid, as everything looks fine until the eyelids move past the limits of where they should be. On your limit location constraints, set the minimum/maximum (depending on whether the eyelid is a top or bottom one) and set the value to be (-)0.0725. That will limit the eyelids position so that they cant move past each other.

If that is not an option, you will have to adjust the mesh so that it doesn't get stretched in a bad way when the eyelids move to the extremes.